# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "OFFER_SERVICE" not found

Tags: mysql, database, h2

I'm using a H2 Database and wanted to add a new column on one of the tables using the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD offer_service boolean
```

That worked out fine but I also have an sql file on my server with the following input:

```
INSERT INTO restaurant (id, sort_index, name, telephone, location_id, deleted) 
  VALUES
  (1, 10, 'Cafe Boy', '079 999 88 77', 1, false),
  (2, 20, 'Huusbeiz', '079 999 88 77', 1, false),
  (3, 10, 'Forza',    '079 999 88 77', 2, false),
  (4, 20, 'Veneto',   '079 999 88 77', 2, false),
  (5, 10, 'Mr. I',    '079 999 88 77', 3, false)
;
```

Now I wanted to add the column I just created in there like so:

```
INSERT INTO restaurant (id, sort_index, name, telephone, location_id, deleted, offer_service)
  VALUES
  (1, 10, 'Cafe Boy', '079 999 88 77', 1, false, true),
  (2, 20, 'Huusbeiz', '079 999 88 77', 1, false, false),
  (3, 10, 'Forza',    '079 999 88 77', 2, false, false),
  (4, 20, 'Veneto',   '079 999 88 77', 2, false, false),
  (5, 10, 'Mr. I',    '079 999 88 77', 3, false, false)
;
```

For some reason after re-running the server this doesn't work and I get the following error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "OFFER_SERVICE" not found; SQL statement:
>   INSERT INTO restaurant (id, sort_index, ..., etc.)

I've been working on this for the past few hours, help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does the new column actually exist in your table now? Try `select * from restaurant;` Do you see it there?

Comment: Yes, I can see it.